# github pricing plans

Tags: github

I read the github website that they have  paid plans to host code. In their plans, it was mentioned about repositories and collaborators. Repositories is the number of the apps  and Collaborators is the number of people who can access.I would like to know whether  the number of collaborators is including or excluding myself?. For example, If I choose the [micro plan](http://github.com/plans), I can host 5 repositories and have 1 collaborator(excluding me). Am I right?

Comment: I dunno - you should send github this question in that "Confused about which plan to choose?" box at the bottom of the page you linked to.

Answer (score 5):

yes collaborators are people excluding you